# Meteor collection updated from server, not getting sorted reactively on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

In my meteor project i have a collection where i put some logs and i want to display the latest added log from server on the client always first in the list.

My log collection is subscribed in `autorun`, to control the number of the logs loaded by the limit:

```
Template.statistics.onCreated(function(){
 instance.autorun(function () {

         var instance = this;

        instance.limitLogs = new ReactiveVar(20);
        instance.loadedLogs = new ReactiveVar(0);


        var limitLogs = instance.limitLogs.get();
        var subscriptionLogs = instance.subscribe("logs_list",limitLogs);


        // if subscription is ready, set limit to newLimit
        if (subscriptionLogs.ready()) {

            instance.loadedLogs.set(limitLogs);
        } else {
            console.log("> Subscription logs is not ready yet. \n\n");
        }

    });
    instance.getLogsList = function(){

        return logsList.find();
    };

});

Template.statistics.helpers({
     hasMoreLogs: function () {
     return Template.instance().getLogsList().count() >= Template.instance().limitLogs.get();
    } ,
    logs : function(){
           return Template.instance().getLogsList();

    }

});
```

On the server i have:

```
 Meteor.publish("logs_list",function(limit) {
        return  logsList.find({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}},{limit: limit});
    });
```

And in my `collection.js` in the `lib` folder i have:

```
logsList = new Mongo.Collection('logsList');
```

So i have some server code which runs in as job, in `JobCollection`, from this server method i call another server method which inserts data in logs:

```
Meteor.Methods({
 logTask : function(taskId,message,status){
            logsList.insert({
                    jobID : taskId,
                    message : message,
                    status : status,
                    createdAt : new Date()
                }
            );
        } 
});

//... somewhere in job worker
  Meteor.call("logTask", job._doc._id, "something", "failed");
```

Whenever i insert logs from that job worker using my `logTask` server method, i see a new entry on the client in my logs table, but it's not getting sorted by `createdAt`, Hovewer if i update the page, i see that the logs collection is getting ordered as expected.

Like so:

before page reload:

```
message1    Wed Feb 24 2016 07:30:52 GMT+0200
message2    Wed Feb 24 2016 07:36:52 GMT+0200
```

after page reload:

```
message2    Wed Feb 24 2016 07:36:52 GMT+0200
message1    Wed Feb 24 2016 07:30:52 GMT+0200
```

Should the collection be somehow aggregated after insertion to make it re-order on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `{},{sort: {createdAt: -1}}` on client as well.

```
instance.getLogsList = function(){
    return logsList.find({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}});
};
```

I think, since client already has the data and the new data is patched from server to client, it is ordered in such a way before you refresh.